# Trigger on project object to create a new chatter group whenever a new project is created

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to salesforce can anyone help me with the trigger.
I have tried it but not able to fulfill the requirement. Please help me any suggestions are appreciated.
Requirement:
A company wants to do collaboration using chatter group for project. Whenever Enable Collaboration checkbox is checked a respective chatter group should be created.
Note: Only one chatter group should exist for a Project.

```
Trigger:

trigger ChatterGroupCreation on Project__c (after insert,after update) {

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
    ChatterGroupCreationHandler.isProjectInsert(Trigger.new);
}
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
    ChatterGroupCreationHandler.isProjectUpdate(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
}

Handler:

public class ChatterGroupCreationHandler {
static set<Id> projecthavingchatter=new set<Id>();
public static void isProjectInsert(List<Project__c> listProject){
    System.debug('listProject'+listProject);
    List<CollaborationGroup> chattergroup=new List<CollaborationGroup>();
    for(Project__c proj:listProject){
        if(proj.Enable_Collaboration__c==true){
            CollaborationGroup myGroup = new CollaborationGroup();
            myGroup.Name=proj.Name+proj.Id;
            myGroup.CollaborationType='Public';                   
            chattergroup.add(myGroup);
            projecthavingchatter.add(proj.Id);
        }
    }
    System.debug('projecthavingchatter'+projecthavingchatter);
    System.debug('chatter'+chattergroup);
    insert chattergroup;
}


public static void isProjectUpdate(List<Project__c> listProject,Map<Id,Project__c>oldMapProject){
    System.debug('projecthavingchatter'+projecthavingchatter);
    List<CollaborationGroup> chattergroup=new List<CollaborationGroup>();
    for(Project__c proj:listProject){
        Project__c oldProj=oldMapProject.get(proj.Id);
        if(oldProj.Enable_Collaboration__c==false && proj.Enable_Collaboration__c==true && !projecthavingchatter.contains(proj.Id)){

            CollaborationGroup myGroup = new CollaborationGroup();
            myGroup.Name=proj.Name+proj.Id;
            myGroup.CollaborationType='Public';
            chattergroup.add(myGroup);
        }
    }
    system.debug('chatter update'+chattergroup);
    try{
        insert chattergroup;
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

}

The problem is if I have created 2-3 projects of same name then I cannot create a different chatter group for each.
And also whenever I turn the checkbox from false to true in update it should check if there is chatter group created or not.
Please help me.
I have updated the code based on your suggestions can anyone tell me if its correct or not

Comment: You can create a flag / checkbox field to mark whenever a project's chatter group is created. (when the first checkbox is checked and the chatter group creation checkbox is not for example)

Comment: If I add flag the in bulk it will not work

Comment: Are you sure this is what they want. Chatter groups have some limitations. A user can only be a member of 300 groups and a company can have "only" 30.000 groups. There is a chatter feed at the top of a project. Can that not be used?

Comment: No the I have to use chatter groups only . But I am not able to check it in update whether it has created chatter or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the chatter group unique, for example

```
myGroup.Name = proj.Name + ' - ' + proj.Id;
```

In such a case you'll be able to create chatter groups for the projects with the same name.

---

For handling update operation you there is 2 option:

1) on update operation just collect all the unique combinations for a chatter group name (project name + Id) and query chatter groups with these names -> see what groups already exist and create missing ones

```
public static void isProjectUpdate(List<Project__c> listProject,Map<Id,Project__c>oldMapProject){

    Map<String, Project__c> chatterGroupNameToProject = new Mapm<String, Project__c>();

    for (Project__c p : listProject) {
        Project__c oldProj = oldMapProject.get(p.Id);
        if (oldProj.Enable_Collaboration__c == false && p.Enable_Collaboration__c == true && !projecthavingchatter.contains(p.Id)) {
            String quniqueChatterGroupName = p.Name + ' - ' + p.Id;
            chatterGroupNameToProject.put(quniqueChatterGroupName, p);
        }
    }

    if (chatterGroupNameToProject.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    for (CollaborationGroup cg : [SELECT Name FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name IN :chatterGroupNameToProject.keySet()]) {
        // Means that group already exist
        chatterGroupNameToProject.remove(cg.Name);
    };

    List<CollaborationGroup> chattergroups = new List<CollaborationGroup>();
    for (Project__c proj : chatterGroupNameToProject) {
        CollaborationGroup myGroup = new CollaborationGroup();

        String quniqueChatterGroupName = p.Name + ' - ' + p.Id;

        myGroup.Name = proj.Name+proj.Id;
        myGroup.CollaborationType = 'Public';
        chattergroups.add(myGroup);
    }
    system.debug('chatter update'+chattergroups);
    if (!chattergroups.isEmpty()) {
        insert chattergroups;
    }
}
```

2)You could use `Database.SaveResult[] insertResults = Database.insert(chatter, false);` method with `false`, if the group name already exists - the group will not be created(see [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm)). But here you have to process the result of the insert call `insertResults`, to see if there are any error except the error for chatter group that the name is not unique

```
public static void isProjectUpdate(List<Project__c> listProject,Map<Id,Project__c>oldMapProject){

    List<CollaborationGroup> chattergroups = new List<CollaborationGroup>();

    for (Project__c p : listProject) {
        Project__c oldProj = oldMapProject.get(p.Id);
        if (oldProj.Enable_Collaboration__c == false && p.Enable_Collaboration__c == true && !projecthavingchatter.contains(p.Id)) {
            CollaborationGroup myGroup = new CollaborationGroup();

            String quniqueChatterGroupName = p.Name + ' - ' + p.Id;

            myGroup.Name = proj.Name+proj.Id;
            myGroup.CollaborationType = 'Public';
            chattergroups.add(myGroup);
        }
    }

    if (!chattergroups.isEmpty()) {
        Database.SaveResult[] insertResults = Database.insert(chattergroups, false);

        for (Database.SaveResult res : insertResults) {
            if (!res.isSuccess()) {
                for (Database.Error e : res.getErrors()) {
                    // it means that the error is not related to a duplicate name and you have to handle it
                    if (e.getStatusCode() != StatusCode.DUPLICATE_VALUE) {
                        // handle the error
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the update logic . Actually I am not getting what are you trying to say

Comment: @maria I've updated the answer with the examples

Comment: Thank you for your help